# Calculate the count of nested objects with C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, aggregation-framework

I am developing a software using ASP.Net core 2.0 web api. I need to calculate count of some fields in my collection.
I have data in my collection in MongoDB as below. I need to find how many Tags and how many sensors do I have in my collection. A specific endpoint has multi tags and each tag has multi sensors.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aef51dfaf42ea1b70d0c4db"),    
    "EndpointId" : "89799bcc-e86f-4c8a-b340-8b5ed53caf83",    
    "DateTime" : ISODate("2018-05-06T19:05:02.666Z"),
    "Url" : "test",
    "Tags" : [ 
        {
            "Uid" : "C1:3D:CA:D4:45:11",
            "Type" : 1,
            "DateTime" : ISODate("2018-05-06T19:05:02.666Z"),
            "Sensors" : [ 
                {
                    "Type" : 1,
                    "Value" : NumberDecimal("-95")
                }, 
                {
                    "Type" : 2,
                    "Value" : NumberDecimal("-59")
                }, 
                {
                    "Type" : 3,
                    "Value" : NumberDecimal("11.029802536740132")
                }, 
                {
                    "Type" : 4,
                    "Value" : NumberDecimal("27.25")
                }, 
                {
                    "Type" : 6,
                    "Value" : NumberDecimal("2924")
                }
            ]
        },         
        {
            "Uid" : "C1:3D:CA:D4:45:11",
            "Type" : 1,
            "DateTime" : ISODate("2018-05-06T19:05:02.666Z"),
            "Sensors" : [ 
                {
                    "Type" : 1,
                    "Value" : NumberDecimal("-95")
                }, 
                {
                    "Type" : 2,
                    "Value" : NumberDecimal("-59")
                }, 
                {
                    "Type" : 3,
                    "Value" : NumberDecimal("11.413037961112279")
                }, 
                {
                    "Type" : 4,
                    "Value" : NumberDecimal("27.25")
                }, 
                {
                    "Type" : 6,
                    "Value" : NumberDecimal("2924")
                }
            ]
        },          
        {
            "Uid" : "E5:FA:2A:35:AF:DD",
            "Type" : 1,
            "DateTime" : ISODate("2018-05-06T19:05:02.666Z"),
            "Sensors" : [ 
                {
                    "Type" : 1,
                    "Value" : NumberDecimal("-97")
                }, 
                {
                    "Type" : 2,
                    "Value" : NumberDecimal("-58")
                }, 
                {
                    "Type" : 3,
                    "Value" : NumberDecimal("10.171658037099185")
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aef51e0af42ea1b70d0c4dc"),    
    "EndpointId" : "89799bcc-e86f-4c8a-b340-8b5ed53caf83",    
    "Url" : "test",
    "Tags" : [ 
        {
            "Uid" : "E2:02:00:18:DA:40",
            "Type" : 1,
            "DateTime" : ISODate("2018-05-06T19:05:04.574Z"),
            "Sensors" : [ 
                {
                    "Type" : 1,
                    "Value" : NumberDecimal("-98")
                }, 
                {
                    "Type" : 2,
                    "Value" : NumberDecimal("-65")
                }, 
                {
                    "Type" : 3,
                    "Value" : NumberDecimal("7.845424441900629")
                }, 
                {
                    "Type" : 4,
                    "Value" : NumberDecimal("0.0")
                }, 
                {
                    "Type" : 6,
                    "Value" : NumberDecimal("3012")
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "Uid" : "12:3B:6A:1A:B7:F9",
            "Type" : 1,
            "DateTime" : ISODate("2018-05-06T19:05:04.574Z"),
            "Sensors" : [ 
                {
                    "Type" : 1,
                    "Value" : NumberDecimal("-95")
                }, 
                {
                    "Type" : 2,
                    "Value" : NumberDecimal("-59")
                }, 
                {
                    "Type" : 3,
                    "Value" : NumberDecimal("12.939770381907275")
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to calculate the count of Tags and Sensors related to specific EndpointId. How can I write that query in mongoDB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query to count the "unique" occurances within an `"EndpointId"` of each of the `"Uid"` in `"Tags"` and the `"Type"` in `"Sensors"` would be:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$Tags" },
  { "$unwind": "$Tags.Sensors" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "EndpointId": "$EndpointId",
      "Uid": "$Tags.Uid",
      "Type": "$Tags.Sensors.Type"
    },
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "EndpointId": "$_id.EndpointId",
      "Uid": "$_id.Uid",
    },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id.EndpointId",
    "tagCount": { "$sum": 1 },
    "sensorCount": { "$sum": "$count" }
  }}
])
```

Or for C#

```
    var results = collection.AsQueryable()
      .SelectMany(p => p.Tags, (p, tag) => new
        {
          EndpointId = p.EndpointId,
          Uid = tag.Uid,
          Sensors = tag.Sensors
        }
      )
      .SelectMany(p => p.Sensors, (p, sensor) => new
        {
          EndpointId = p.EndpointId,
          Uid = p.Uid,
          Type = sensor.Type
        }
      )
      .GroupBy(p => new { EndpointId = p.EndpointId, Uid = p.Uid, Type = p.Type })
      .GroupBy(p => new { EndpointId = p.Key.EndpointId, Uid = p.Key.Uid },
        (k, s) => new { Key = k, count = s.Count() }
      )
      .GroupBy(p => p.Key.EndpointId,
        (k, s) => new
        {
          EndpointId = k,
          tagCount = s.Count(),
          sensorCount = s.Sum(x => x.count)
        }
      );
```

Which outputs:

```
{
  "EndpointId" : "89799bcc-e86f-4c8a-b340-8b5ed53caf83",
  "tagCount" : 4,
  "sensorCount" : 16
}
```

Though actually the "most efficient" way to do this considering that the documents presented have unique values for `"Uid"` anyway would be to `$reduce` the amounts within the documents itself:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$EndpointId",
    "tags": {
      "$sum": {
        "$size": { "$setUnion": ["$Tags.Uid",[]] }
      }
    },
    "sensors": {
      "$sum": {
        "$sum": {
          "$map": {
            "input": { "$setUnion": ["$Tags.Uid",[]] },
            "as": "tag",
            "in": {
              "$size": {
                "$reduce": {
                  "input": {
                    "$filter": {
                      "input": {
                        "$map": {
                          "input": "$Tags",
                          "in": {
                            "Uid": "$$this.Uid",
                            "Type": "$$this.Sensors.Type"
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$this.Uid", "$$tag" ] }
                    }
                  },
                  "initialValue": [],
                  "in": { "$setUnion": [ "$$value", "$$this.Type" ] }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

The statement does not really map well to LINQ however, so you would be required to use the `BsonDocument` interface to build the BSON for the statement. And of course where the same `"Uid"` values "did" in fact occur within multiple documents in the collection, then the `$unwind` statements are necessary in order to "group" those together across documents from within the array entries.

---

### Original

You solve this by obtaining the [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) of the arrays. For the outer array this is simply applying to field path of the array in the document, and for the inner array items you need to process with [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) in order to process each `"Tags"` element and then obtain the [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) of `"Sensors"` and [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) the resulting array to reduce to the overall count.

Per document that would be:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "tags": { "$size": "$Tags" },
    "sensors": {
      "$sum": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$Tags",
           "in": { "$size": "$$this.Sensors" }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Which where you have assigned to classes in your C# code would be like:

```
collection.AsQueryable()
  .Select(p => new
    {
      tags = p.Tags.Count(),
      sensors = p.Tags.Select(x => x.Sensors.Count()).Sum()
    }
  );
```

Where those return:

```
{ "tags" : 3, "sensors" : 13 }
{ "tags" : 2, "sensors" : 8 }
```

Where you want to [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) the results, as for example over the whole collection, then you would do:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  /* The shell would use $match for "query" conditions */
  //{ "$match": { "EndpointId": "89799bcc-e86f-4c8a-b340-8b5ed53caf83" } },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "tags": { "$sum": { "$size": "$Tags" } },
    "sensors": {
      "$sum": {
        "$sum": {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$Tags",
             "in": { "$size": "$$this.Sensors" }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Which for your C# code like before would be:

```
collection.AsQueryable()
  .GroupBy(p => "", (k,s) => new
    {
      tags = s.Sum(p => p.Tags.Count()),
      sensors = s.Sum(p => p.Tags.Select(x => x.Sensors.Count()).Sum())
    }
  );
```

Where those return:

```
{ "tags" : 5, "sensors" : 21 }
```

And for `"EndpointId`, then you simply use that field as the grouping key, rather than the `null` or `0` as it gets applied by the C# driver mapping:

```
collection.AsQueryable()
  /* Use the Where if you want a query to match only those documents */
  //.Where(p => p.EndpointId == "89799bcc-e86f-4c8a-b340-8b5ed53caf83")            
  .GroupBy(p => p.EndpointId, (k,s) => new
    {
      tags = s.Sum(p => p.Tags.Count()),
      sensors = s.Sum(p => p.Tags.Select(x => x.Sensors.Count()).Sum())
    }
  );
```

Which is of course the same sum of the two document sample you gave us:

```
{ "tags" : 5, "sensors" : 21 }
```

So these are very simple results, with simple pipeline execution once you get used to the syntax.

I suggest familiarizing yourself with the [Aggregation Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) from the core documentation, and of course the ["LINQ Cheat Sheet"](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/aec938641c4d7fa5d812b13420efafbba63430e9/Docs/reference/content/reference/driver/expressions.md) of expressions and their usage mapping from withing the C# Driver code repository.

Also see the general [LINQ Reference](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.5/reference/driver/crud/linq/) in the C# Driver reference for other examples of how this maps onto the Aggregation Framework of MongoDB in general.

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for answer. It was really good. But in this case for every unique `EndpointId`, sum of all unique `Tags.Uid` defines that how many tags this endpoint has. and `sum of (sum of every unique Sensors.Type for every unique Tags.Uid)` defines that how many sensors this Endpoint has. I think the query that you wrote above doesn't give the right answer.

Comment: @M.Taherian Added for those conditions above. Please make sure on future questions that you actually include such details in the question as you ask. The question is answered. If you have another question or new conditions then [Ask a New Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) instead. You will generally find that people are not prepared to change answers from what you originally asked them for, so this is a one time thing.

Comment: I just want to say thank you for writing this amazing answer, this helped me learn and understand the aggregation and LINQ in mongodb a lot.