# How can I decrease unwind stages in aggregation pipeline for nested documents?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am new in mongodb and trying to work with nested documents.I have a query as below

```
    db.EndpointData.aggregate([
{ "$group" : { "_id" : "$EndpointId", "RequestCount" : { "$sum" : 1 }, "FirstActivity" : { "$min" : "$DateTime" }, "LastActivity" : { "$max" : "$DateTime" }, "Tags" : { "$push" : "$Tags" } } }, 
{ "$unwind" : "$Tags" }, 
{ "$unwind" : "$Tags" }, 
{ "$group" : { "_id" : "$_id", "RequestCount" : { "$first" : "$RequestCount" }, "Tags" : { "$push" : "$Tags" }, "FirstActivity" : { "$first" : "$FirstActivity" }, "LastActivity" : { "$first" : "$LastActivity" } } }, 
{ "$unwind" : "$Tags" }, 
{ "$unwind" : "$Tags.Sensors" }, 
{ "$group" : { "_id" : { "EndpointId" : "$_id", "Uid" : "$Tags.Uid", "Type" : "$Tags.Sensors.Type" }, "RequestCount" : { "$first" : "$RequestCount" }, "FirstActivity" : { "$first" : "$FirstActivity" }, "LastActivity" : { "$first" : "$LastActivity" } } }, 
{ "$group" : { "_id" : { "EndpointId" : "$_id.EndpointId", "Uid" : "$_id.Uid" }, "count" : { "$sum" : 1 }, "RequestCount" : { "$first" : "$RequestCount" }, "FirstActivity" : { "$first" : "$FirstActivity" }, "LastActivity" : { "$first" : "$LastActivity" } } }, 
{ "$group" : { "_id" : "$_id.EndpointId", "TagCount" : { "$sum" : 1 }, "SensorCount" : { "$sum" : "$count" }, "RequestCount" : { "$first" : "$RequestCount" }, "FirstActivity" : { "$first" : "$FirstActivity" }, "LastActivity" : { "$first" : "$LastActivity" } } }])
```

and my data structure is as below

```
{
  "_id": "6aef51dfaf42ea1b70d0c4db",  
  "EndpointId": "98799bcc-e86f-4c8a-b340-8b5ed53caf83",  
  "DateTime": "2018-05-06T19:05:02.666Z",
  "Url": "test",
  "Tags": [
    {
      "Uid": "C1:3D:CA:D4:45:11",
      "Type": 1,
      "DateTime": "2018-05-06T19:05:02.666Z",
      "Sensors": [
        {
          "Type": 1,
          "Value": { "$numberDecimal": "-95" }
        },
        {
          "Type": 2,
          "Value": { "$numberDecimal": "-59" }
        },
        {
          "Type": 3,
          "Value": { "$numberDecimal": "11.029802536740132" }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Uid": "C1:3D:CA:D4:45:11",
      "Type": 1,
      "DateTime": "2018-05-06T19:05:02.666Z",
      "Sensors": [
        {
          "Type": 1,
          "Value": { "$numberDecimal": "-92" }
        },
        {
          "Type": 2,
          "Value": { "$numberDecimal": "-59" }
        }
      ]
    }   
  ]
}
```

This query **works fine** and **correct**. I count Tags, Sensors and repeat times of each EdpointID. But **the problem is** when I work with large size of data (about 10,000,000 documents) I get **memory problem**. It seems having 4 levels of unwind make problem in this query. How can I reduce unwinds in this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your data has unique sensor and tag readings per document, which to date what you have presented appears to, then you simply don't need [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) at all.

In fact, all you really need is a single [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/):

```
db.endpoints.aggregate([
  // In reality you would $match to limit the selection of documents
  { "$match": { 
    "DateTime": { "$gte": new Date("2018-05-01"), "$lt": new Date("2018-06-01") }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$EndpointId",
    "FirstActivity" : { "$min" : "$DateTime" },
    "LastActivity" : { "$max" : "$DateTime" },
    "RequestCount": { "$sum": 1 },
    "TagCount": {
      "$sum": {
        "$size": { "$setUnion": ["$Tags.Uid",[]] }
      }
    },
    "SensorCount": {
      "$sum": {
        "$sum": {
          "$map": {
            "input": { "$setUnion": ["$Tags.Uid",[]] },
            "as": "tag",
            "in": {
              "$size": {
                "$reduce": {
                  "input": {
                    "$filter": {
                      "input": {
                        "$map": {
                          "input": "$Tags",
                          "in": {
                            "Uid": "$$this.Uid",
                            "Type": "$$this.Sensors.Type"
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$this.Uid", "$$tag" ] }
                    }
                  },
                  "initialValue": [],
                  "in": { "$setUnion": [ "$$value", "$$this.Type" ] }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Or if you actually do need to accumulate those "unique" values of "Sensors" and "Tags" from across different documents, then you still need initial [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) statements to get the right grouping, but nowhere near as much as you presently have:

```
db.endpoints.aggregate([
  // In reality you would $match to limit the selection of documents
  { "$match": { 
    "DateTime": { "$gte": new Date("2018-05-01"), "$lt": new Date("2018-06-01") }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$Tags" },
  { "$unwind": "$Tags.Sensors" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "EndpointId": "$EndpointId",
      "Uid": "$Tags.Uid",
      "Type": "$Tags.Sensors.Type"
    },
    "FirstActivity": { "$min": "$DateTime" },
    "LastActivity": { "$max": "$DateTime" },
    "RequestCount": { "$addToSet": "$_id" }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "EndpointId": "$_id.EndpointId",
      "Uid": "$_id.Uid",
    },
    "FirstActivity": { "$min": "$FirstActivity" },
    "LastActivity": { "$max": "$LastActivity" },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 },
    "RequestCount": { "$addToSet": "$RequestCount" }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id.EndpointId",
    "FirstActivity": { "$min": "$FirstActivity" },
    "LastActivity": { "$max": "$LastActivity" },
    "TagCount": { "$sum": 1 },
    "SensorCount": { "$sum": "$count" },
    "RequestCount": { "$addToSet": "$RequestCount" }
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "RequestCount": {
      "$size": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": {
            "$reduce": {
              "input": "$RequestCount",
              "initialValue": [],
              "in": { "$setUnion": [ "$$value", "$$this" ] }
            }
          },
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": { "$setUnion": [ "$$value", "$$this" ] }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
],{ "allowDiskUse": true })
```

And from MongoDB 4.0 you can use [`$toString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/) on the `ObjectId` within `_id` and simply merge the unique keys for those in order to keep the `RequestCount` using [`$mergeObjects`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/). This is cleaner and a bit more scalable than pushing nested array content and flattening it

```
db.endpoints.aggregate([
  // In reality you would $match to limit the selection of documents
  { "$match": { 
    "DateTime": { "$gte": new Date("2018-05-01"), "$lt": new Date("2018-06-01") }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$Tags" },
  { "$unwind": "$Tags.Sensors" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "EndpointId": "$EndpointId",
      "Uid": "$Tags.Uid",
      "Type": "$Tags.Sensors.Type"
    },
    "FirstActivity": { "$min": "$DateTime" },
    "LastActivity": { "$max": "$DateTime" },
    "RequestCount": {
      "$mergeObjects": {
        "$arrayToObject": [[{ "k": { "$toString": "$_id" }, "v": 1 }]]
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "EndpointId": "$_id.EndpointId",
      "Uid": "$_id.Uid",
    },
    "FirstActivity": { "$min": "$FirstActivity" },
    "LastActivity": { "$max": "$LastActivity" },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 },
    "RequestCount": { "$mergeObjects": "$RequestCount" }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id.EndpointId",
    "FirstActivity": { "$min": "$FirstActivity" },
    "LastActivity": { "$max": "$LastActivity" },
    "TagCount": { "$sum": 1 },
    "SensorCount": { "$sum": "$count" },
    "RequestCount": { "$mergeObjects": "$RequestCount" }
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "RequestCount": {
      "$size": {
        "$objectToArray": "$RequestCount"
      }
    }
  }}
],{ "allowDiskUse": true })
```

Either form returns the same data, though the order of keys in the result may vary:

```
{
        "_id" : "89799bcc-e86f-4c8a-b340-8b5ed53caf83",
        "FirstActivity" : ISODate("2018-05-06T19:05:02.666Z"),
        "LastActivity" : ISODate("2018-05-06T19:05:02.666Z"),
        "RequestCount" : 2,
        "TagCount" : 4,
        "SensorCount" : 16
}
```

The result is obtained from these sample documents which you originally gave as a sample source in [the original question on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50243453/2313887):

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aef51dfaf42ea1b70d0c4db"),    
    "EndpointId" : "89799bcc-e86f-4c8a-b340-8b5ed53caf83",    
    "DateTime" : ISODate("2018-05-06T19:05:02.666Z"),
    "Url" : "test",
    "Tags" : [ 
        {
            "Uid" : "C1:3D:CA:D4:45:11",
            "Type" : 1,
            "DateTime" : ISODate("2018-05-06T19:05:02.666Z"),
            "Sensors" : [ 
                {
                    "Type" : 1,
                    "Value" : NumberDecimal("-95")
                }, 
                {
                    "Type" : 2,
                    "Value" : NumberDecimal("-59")
                }, 
                {
                    "Type" : 3,
                    "Value" : NumberDecimal("11.029802536740132")
                }, 
                {
                    "Type" : 4,
                    "Value" : NumberDecimal("27.25")
                }, 
                {
                    "Type" : 6,
                    "Value" : NumberDecimal("2924")
                }
            ]
        },         
        {
            "Uid" : "C1:3D:CA:D4:45:11",
            "Type" : 1,
            "DateTime" : ISODate("2018-05-06T19:05:02.666Z"),
            "Sensors" : [ 
                {
                    "Type" : 1,
                    "Value" : NumberDecimal("-95")
                }, 
                {
                    "Type" : 2,
                    "Value" : NumberDecimal("-59")
                }, 
                {
                    "Type" : 3,
                    "Value" : NumberDecimal("11.413037961112279")
                }, 
                {
                    "Type" : 4,
                    "Value" : NumberDecimal("27.25")
                }, 
                {
                    "Type" : 6,
                    "Value" : NumberDecimal("2924")
                }
            ]
        },          
        {
            "Uid" : "E5:FA:2A:35:AF:DD",
            "Type" : 1,
            "DateTime" : ISODate("2018-05-06T19:05:02.666Z"),
            "Sensors" : [ 
                {
                    "Type" : 1,
                    "Value" : NumberDecimal("-97")
                }, 
                {
                    "Type" : 2,
                    "Value" : NumberDecimal("-58")
                }, 
                {
                    "Type" : 3,
                    "Value" : NumberDecimal("10.171658037099185")
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aef51e0af42ea1b70d0c4dc"),    
    "EndpointId" : "89799bcc-e86f-4c8a-b340-8b5ed53caf83",    
    "Url" : "test",
    "Tags" : [ 
        {
            "Uid" : "E2:02:00:18:DA:40",
            "Type" : 1,
            "DateTime" : ISODate("2018-05-06T19:05:04.574Z"),
            "Sensors" : [ 
                {
                    "Type" : 1,
                    "Value" : NumberDecimal("-98")
                }, 
                {
                    "Type" : 2,
                    "Value" : NumberDecimal("-65")
                }, 
                {
                    "Type" : 3,
                    "Value" : NumberDecimal("7.845424441900629")
                }, 
                {
                    "Type" : 4,
                    "Value" : NumberDecimal("0.0")
                }, 
                {
                    "Type" : 6,
                    "Value" : NumberDecimal("3012")
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "Uid" : "12:3B:6A:1A:B7:F9",
            "Type" : 1,
            "DateTime" : ISODate("2018-05-06T19:05:04.574Z"),
            "Sensors" : [ 
                {
                    "Type" : 1,
                    "Value" : NumberDecimal("-95")
                }, 
                {
                    "Type" : 2,
                    "Value" : NumberDecimal("-59")
                }, 
                {
                    "Type" : 3,
                    "Value" : NumberDecimal("12.939770381907275")
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Bottom line is that you can either use the first given form here which will accumulate "within each document" and then "accumulate per endpoint" within a single stage and is the most optimal, or you actually require to identify things like the `"Uid"` on the tags or the `"Type"` on the sensor where those values occur more than once over any combination of documents grouping by the endpoint.

Your sample data supplied to date only shows that these values are "unique within each document", therefore the first given form would be most optimal if this is the case for all remaining data.

In the event that it is not, then "unwinding" the two nested arrays in order to "aggregate the detail across documents" is the only way to approach this. You can limit the date range or other criteria as most "queries" typically have some bounds and do not actually work on the "whole" collection data, but the main fact remains that arrays would be "unwound" creating essentially a document copy for every array member.

The point on optimization means that you only need to do this "twice" as there are only two arrays. Doing successive [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) to [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) to [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) is always a sure sign you a doing something really wrong. Once you "take something apart" you should only ever need to "put it back together" **once**. In a series of graded steps as demonstrated here is the **once** approach which optimizes.

Outside of the scope of your question still remains:

- Add other realistic constraints to the query to reduce the documents processed, maybe even do so in "batches" and combine results
- Add the `allowDiskUse` option to the pipeline to let temporary storage be used. ( actually demonstrated on the commands )
- Consider that "nested arrays" are probably not the best storage method for the analysis you want to do. It's always more efficient when you know you need to [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) to simply write the data in that "unwound" form directly into a collection.

Comment: Thank you very much. It was more than just an answer. It was a MongoDB course. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with data on the order of 10,000,000 documents, you're going to run into aggregation pipeline size limits easily. Specifically, [according to the MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/), there is a pipeline RAM use limit of 100MB. If each document has at least 10 bytes of data, then that's enough to hit that limit, and your documents would absolutely exceed that amount.

There are a few options available to you to resolve this problem:

1) You can use the `allowDiskUse` option as noted in the documentation.

2) You can project your documents further between unwind stages to limit document size (very unlikely to be enough on its own).

3) You can periodically generate summary documents on subsets of your data, and then perform your aggregations on those summary documents. If, for example, you run summary documents on subsets of size 1,000, you can reduce the number of documents in your pipelines from 10,000,000 to just 10,000.

4) You can look into `sharding` your collection and running these aggregate operations on a cluster to reduce the load on any single server.

Options 1 and 2 are both very short-term solutions. They're easy to implement, but won't help much in the long run. Options 3 and 4, however, are far more involved and trickier to implement, but will provide the greatest amount of scalability and are more likely to continue meeting your needs long-term.

Do be warned, however, that if you plan to approach option 4, you need to be very prepared. A sharded collection cannot be unsharded, and messing up can cause potentially irreparable data loss. Having a dedicated DBA with experience with MongoDB clusters is recommended.

Comment: Thank you very much for valuable information. Do you have any idea how can I improve my query (to decrease unwinds)?

Comment: Whilst this is good "general" advice, the actual main issue is with the construction of the statement, which attempts to compact documents, unwind them and compact over and over in order to count some things. It **can** really be improved. The core problem is one that happens here all the time, where the person asking gets an initial "query", then wants to add something and gets responses from different people for each "add". This is what happened here, as I did give this person a "very streamlined" initial operation. But it's just "gone south" as others have added to it.